# Why is Instruments reporting this as a memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
NSMutableArray *bar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSMutableDictionary *foo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[foo setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"yay"];
[bar addObject:foo];

[foo release];
```

Instruments is showing that foo is leaking. I understand why that is happening. Foo's retain count when alloc'd is 1. Then when bar addObject's foo, the retain count goes to 2. Later when I release foo, it goes down back to 1. Still a leak. However, later on in my code, (in a separate method, which is why I think this might be shown as a leak)

```
[bar removeAllObjects];
```

Why is foo shown as leaking if I do removeAllObjects later on?

** NOTE **

I didn't include it in my original post, but bar is indeed being released in the classes dealloc method.

Comment: Where is [bar removeAllObjects] called? Is it called indefinitely? (in a dealloc method for example). Does calling removeAllObjects immediately after [foo release] cause a leak to still be observed?

Comment: Perspx: bar is released in a dealloc method, it is a class instance. I need it around for the duration of the class otherwise. I do release it though in dealloc.

Answer (score 3):

Given what you show, it is `bar` that never gets released. Calling `[bar removeAllObjects]` only removes the objects it contains. Instead, you should call `[bar release]` when you are done with `bar`. This will automatically release all of the objects that `bar` holds, plus release the bar object itself.

You state that you understand the memory management concepts, so perhaps you just didn't show `bar` being released in your example.

**edit:** I think craig has the right idea in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726944/why-is-instruments-reporting-this-as-a-memory-leak/727108#727108). One way to avoid the warning (maybe) would be to allocate `bar` in the class `init` method. I usually find it beneficial to maintain a symmetry between my `init` and `dealloc` methods when it comes to member variables, and this would be a good example:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]) == nil) { return nil; }

    bar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [bar release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)YourMethod
{
    NSMutableDictionary *foo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    [foo setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"yay"];
    [bar addObject:foo];
    [foo release];
}
```

Comment: I think this might be it.  foo will be marked as leaked if a reference to bar is lost without first releasing it.

Comment: His comment indicates that bar is, in fact, released. Oh well!

Answer (score 3):

I think (and I think you hinted at this possibility as well) that Instruments is marking it as a *potential* leak, because it hasn't looked ahead far enough to see that bar will be responsible for removing/releasing all its objects in said separate method..

Comment: I think this is it. Instruments probably flags the fact that bar is allocated within this method's scope, but not released there.

Comment: Yea, I've had issues similar to this one before. Instruments definitely helps in certain situations, but it will never replace sitting down and looking at the code by hand.

Comment: Amen. I don't think anything will replace looking at code by hand for a long time : )

Comment: Ugh, so if it isn't released/freed in the same method, does that imply that my code is probably wrong and should be re-designed?

Comment: No! It means that Instruments isn't actually smart enough to read through your code to see that you're in fact doing it properly.

Comment: No, Instruments doesn’t work like that; it doesn’t look at your code at all. If Instruments is reporting a leak, it means that nothing in your program is pointing at the object. The most likely explanation is a retain imbalance for bar (or its owner).

Comment: BUT Ahruman, is it reporting that nothing in your program is pointing to your object, or nothing in the scope of the method? I get alot of leaks using the NSXMLParser delegate methods, because they're alloced in the didStartElement method, but released in another method (or even above the original alloc in a conditional statement).

Answer (score 0):

The NSMutableArray should be releasing it when removeAllObjects is called. You shouldn't need to release or add it to an autorelease pool.

From O'Reilly's chapeter on Memory Management:

> When you add an object to a collection, it is retained. When you remove an object from a collection, it is released. Releasing a collection object (such as an NSArray) releases all objects stored in it as well.

Perhaps something else is going on in instruments?